# How can I know if the user selected the same item in a select box

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I have a select box that needs to act even if the user selects the currently selected item. I have used onChange (via JQuery) but it doesn't fire if the same item is selected because it hasn't changed.

Is this even possible?

Comment: Maybe you should change your design.

Comment: Is this an internal App?  If it is, you can get away with hooking onto the 'click' event for the 'option' element, but this will work only in non-IE browsers.

Comment: nope gotta be cross browser so there fore I'm guessing that there is no option for this... Sad

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure i understand your question clearly cause of my English. You want to know when a checkbox is clicked if it is already checked you want to fire a function. If i'm right then you can do it in many ways. E.g If you have 2 classes for your checkbox checked or unchecked you can look if that checkbox got "checked" class with .hasClass or you can store index of a checkbox in an array when it is clicked, and every click on a checkbox you can search array if that array has index of that checkbox. If result is true, you fire your function.

Answer (score 0):

You can try in each  of your select box to include the onclick event and call your desired function when that happens. 
Or you can use the onblur event in your  element and fire your function when that happens.